# wpf multiple view based on screen resolution

Tags: wpf, screen-orientation, visualstatemanager

to optimize how an image is shown on the screen i need to design two views, detect the screen ratio (4:3 or 16:9 and above) and switch between them.

On a 4:3 screen the content should be displayed vertically (by rows) like this:

---

```
toolbars 25%
----------------
image  
----------------
toolbars 25%
----------------
```

On a 16:9 monitor horizontally (by columns) like this:

```
t |  i  | t
o |  m  | o
o |  a  | o
l |  g  | l
b |  e  | b
a |     | a
r |     | r
s |     | s
  |     |
```

Screen ratio detection is done.
I tried to work with visual state manager and datatemplate to switch views but i could not end up proper 'standard' solution to this googling.

Any guideline?

Comment: this is just an idea but you could try using attached properties on a grid and have your own code manipulate the children of the grid. (making them change their Grid.Row/Column values depending on ratio. worth a try. that's what i would be doing i guess. Another option would be a templateselector

Comment: i tried your first suggestion before asking here with little satisfatction. can you please provide a tiny example of the templateselector technique? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the job as well i suppose. There's some coding left for you though

Usage:

```
<Window x:Class="ResponsiveWpfLayout.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:responsiveWpfLayout="clr-namespace:ResponsiveWpfLayout"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <responsiveWpfLayout:ResponsiveLayout>
            <responsiveWpfLayout:ResponsiveLayout.DefaultTemplate>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Border Background="Red">
                        <TextBlock>Layout A</TextBlock>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </responsiveWpfLayout:ResponsiveLayout.DefaultTemplate>
            <responsiveWpfLayout:ResponsiveLayout.AlternativeTemplate>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Border Background="Green">
                        <TextBlock>Layout B</TextBlock>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </responsiveWpfLayout:ResponsiveLayout.AlternativeTemplate>
        </responsiveWpfLayout:ResponsiveLayout>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

ResponsiveLayout.cs

```
public class ResponsiveLayout : Control
    {
        static ResponsiveLayout()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(ResponsiveLayout), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(ResponsiveLayout)));
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty DefaultTemplateProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "DefaultTemplate", typeof (ControlTemplate), typeof (ResponsiveLayout), new PropertyMetadata(default(ControlTemplate)));

        public ControlTemplate DefaultTemplate
        {
            get { return (ControlTemplate) GetValue(DefaultTemplateProperty); }
            set { SetValue(DefaultTemplateProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty AlternativeTemplateProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "AlternativeTemplate", typeof (ControlTemplate), typeof (ResponsiveLayout), new PropertyMetadata(default(ControlTemplate)));

        public ControlTemplate AlternativeTemplate
        {
            get { return (ControlTemplate) GetValue(AlternativeTemplateProperty); }
            set { SetValue(AlternativeTemplateProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ActiveTemplateProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "ActiveTemplate", typeof (ControlTemplate), typeof (ResponsiveLayout), new PropertyMetadata(default(ControlTemplate)));

        public ControlTemplate ActiveTemplate
        {
            get { return (ControlTemplate) GetValue(ActiveTemplateProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ActiveTemplateProperty, value); }
        }

        protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size arrangeBounds)
        {
            if (arrangeBounds.Width > arrangeBounds.Height)
            {
                ActiveTemplate = DefaultTemplate;
            }
            else
            {
                ActiveTemplate = AlternativeTemplate;
            }

            return base.ArrangeOverride(arrangeBounds);
        }

        public ResponsiveLayout()
        {
            ActiveTemplate = DefaultTemplate;
        }
    }
```

Generic.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ResponsiveWpfLayout">


    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:ResponsiveLayout}">
        <Setter Property="DefaultTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Border Background="Orange">
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="AlternativeTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Border Background="Blue">
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:ResponsiveLayout}">
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                        <ContentControl Template="{TemplateBinding ActiveTemplate}"></ContentControl>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: Since some UI elements are expensive (images and video) is there a way to refer to the exactly same UI element without instantiang a new one in both templates?

Comment: i'm not sure about that. i suppose you can declare a control in resources and have it displayed in both templates by referencing to the template from resources. at least that's what i would try :)